# Deleting all text starting with a specific string in a pandas series

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, substring

I've got the following df called "places"

```
                   place_name
0                 "Palais et bâtiments officiels[modifier | modifier le code]"
1                 "Lieux de culte renommés[modifier | modifier le code]"
2                 "Vestiges gallo-romains[modifier | modifier le code]"
```

As you can see there is a similar substring [modifier | modifier le code] in all the inputs for places["place_name] and I would like to delete the substring.

I tried the following two techniques

```
places["place_name"] = places["place_name"].apply(lambda x: re.sub("\\[modifier \\| modifier le code\\]", "", x))

places["places_name"] = places["place_name"].str.replace("[modifier | modifier le code]", "", regex=False)
```

None of these work because I think the problem is that the substring I am trying to delete is stuck with another substring (note that there is no space at beginning) so I think the code does not recognise it as a string in itself. I have been trying to split this using split() method but I have the same issue since there is no space at the beginning of the string I am trying to delete.

Final output should be

```
                   place_name
0                 "Palais et bâtiments officiels"
1                 "Lieux de culte renommés"
2                 "Vestiges gallo-romains"
```

I have tried to look for other solutions but can't find any, I know there are lot of questions with strings but can't find specific solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
places["place_name"] = places["place_name"].str.split('\\[modifier').str[0]
```

Basically, split your string on `'[modifier'` and pick the the first value(`[0]`]

Comment: @aramis You may yse `"[modifier"` with `rsplit` since it does not use a regex and you only have one `[modifier` anyway in the string, see my answer with a couple more solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

1. Removing all starting from 0+ whitespaces and `[modifier`:

```py
places["place_name"].str.replace(r'\s*\[modifier.*', '')
```

Here, `\s*` matches 0+ whitespaces, `\[` matches `[` and `modifier.*`  matches `modifier` and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGwbli/3).

2. Extracting all text from the beginning of the string till the first `[`:

```py
places["place_name"] = places["place_name"].str.extract(r'^([^][]+)', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGwbli/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^][]+)` - Capturing group 1 (`Seris.str.extract` requires a capturing group to return any value): one or more chars other than `]` and `[`.

Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> places = pd.DataFrame({'place_name':["Palais et bâtiments officiels[modifier | modifier le code]","Lieux de culte renommés[modifier | modifier le code]","Vestiges gallo-romains[modifier | modifier le code]"]})
>>> places["place_name"] = places["place_name"].str.extract(r'^([^][]+)', expand=False)
>>> places
                      place_name
0  Palais et bâtiments officiels
1        Lieux de culte renommés
2         Vestiges gallo-romains

>>> places["place_name"].str.replace(r'\s*\[modifier.*', '')
0    Palais et bâtiments officiels
1          Lieux de culte renommés
2           Vestiges gallo-romains
```

And if you prefer `split`, you may use `Seris.str.rsplit` that uses a literal string, not a regex:

```py
>>> places["place_name"].str.rsplit('[modifier').str[0]
0    Palais et bâtiments officiels
1          Lieux de culte renommés
2           Vestiges gallo-romains
```

Comment: thank you very much for the expansive answer, this is great for this task but also  expanded my knowledge of regex